# Call to request_module() does not return in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am currently struggling with signing files with IMA/EVM signatures.

Similar things were already done on an embedded Linux system based on 3.14.79. Now I am dealing with a system based on Linux 4.14.98.
The problem is not the signing itself but the trouble starts when the new signatures are verified.

The system is currently in non-enforcing state, i.e. a missing or incorrect signature does not cause program termination.

In error case, the system is simply stuck during signature verification. If it happens after entering a command on the shell, I can break with `Ctrl-C`, but if it happens during boot, that's it.

During my bug hunt I sorted out a few bugs in the kernel related to keyring search and integrity keyring cache.
But now I am stuck.

I placed a few `printk` logs in the code and saw that the problem is in [this code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.98/source/crypto/api.c#L219):

```
struct crypto_alg *crypto_larval_lookup(const char *name, u32 type, u32 mask)
{
...
    alg = crypto_alg_lookup(name, type, mask);
    if (!alg && !(mask & CRYPTO_NOLOAD)) {
        request_module("crypto-%s", name);
...
```

Where `name` holds `"pkcs1pad(rsa,sha256)"`

In some cases this function call returns, in other cases it does not return until I enter ´Ctrl-C` or not at all.

I am not sure where to look for further information, wrong configuration, missing flags or any other hint how to solve the issue.

Comment: Commit [6eb864c1d9dd1ef32b88e03c3f49d8be0dab7dcf](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6eb864c1d9dd1ef32b88e03c3f49d8be0dab7dcf) looks relevant. (That appeared in the  4.19.0 kernel.)

Comment: This looks very good and seems to solve the problem! Thanks a lot!